# my code keep showing Cannot find 'test.aux.bcf'

Tags: latex, bibtex, bibliography

This is my test.tex file....

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
citestyle=authoryear
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{ref}



\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\title{\vspace{-1.0cm}\textbf{\Large{This is a title}}} %Title
\mainmatter

some Random Text Yayyyyyyy

some Random Text Yayyyyyyy

some Random Text Yayyyyyyy

Random text here \cite{a1}.

some Random Text Yayyyyyyy

some Random Text Yayyyyyyy \cite{a2}

\backmatter
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and this is my ref.bib file......

```
@article{a1,
  title= "Peter Gabriel Bergmann, Introduction to the theory of relativity",
  author= "Infeld, L"
  journal="Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society",
  volume="49",
  number="7",
  pages="527--529",
  year="1943",
  publisher="American Mathematical Society"
"

@book{a2,
  title="Matrices and tensors in physics",
  author="Joshi, Avinash Wasudeo",
  year="1995",
  publisher="New Age International"
}
```

My error message is,

Process started
INFO - This is Biber 2.16 INFO - Logfile is 'test.aux.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find 'test.aux.bcf'! INFO - ERRORS: 1
Process exited with error(s)

Can anybody help i am tired of this and want to solve this so that i can apply it to my thesis. im using TexMaker.

Comment: It seems you are giving the .aux file to biber, which has to be a misconfiguration of TexMaker

Comment: Can you show your texmaker configuration? The command should be something like `biber %` (without file type)

Comment: You are also missing the filetype in `\addbibresource{ref.bib}`

Comment: And the a1 bib entry is 1) missing the closing `}` 2) missing a comma after the author

Comment: yes it is biber % and it is giving same error for \addbibresource{ref.bib} i have added it before \begin{document}

Answer (score -1):

I have verified that the root was to remove the compiler option to create the LATEX files in the build folder, my computer could not find the .bcf file being in this folder. But once I unchecked the box and the files were in the same folder as the .tex files, it was solved.

On the other hand, the code `\addbibresource{ref}` must appear like `\addbibresource{ref.bib}`.

In the compiler configuration, I have written the path of biber.exe: "C:/Users/juanf/Documents/Programas/LATEX/miktex/bin/x64/biber" %.bcf
(You must put the path that appears in the properties of your biber.exe)
I hope it helps you or other people with the same problem!